# Redux best practices: subscribe once, or as needed?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is it best practice, to subscribe once to the store and re render the whole app, on every dispatch.

index.js:

```
...
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
    document.getElementById('root'),
  );
};

store.subscribe(render);
render();
...
```

or does it make sense, to subscribe where the changes are required?

MyComponent.js:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  ...
  store.subscribe(handleStateUpdate);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Subscribe once, react will be clever enough to only render what has changed.

Comment: Why would you call subscribe? Using selectors subscribes automatically.

Comment: @DennisVash so, both store.subscribe s are unnecessary?

Comment: Truth, just follow the docs https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: @DennisVash thanks man. works as said. not sure, why our prof pushed the "store.subscribe(render);" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-rendering the entire app on every dispatch is a *horrible* idea and should never be done.  On top of that, you should *not* be manually calling `store.subscribe()` in your own code. Instead, you should be using [our official React-Redux library](https://react-redux.js.org), which handles all the store subscription work for you.

Note that per https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store , we recommend calling `useSelector` in many different components across the UI to access data as needed for that component.